# Problem with system of logarythmic equation.

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

So I have this problem with a system of logarytmic equations. Specifically how to get rid of the (ln(x))^2 in order to solve this one.
I know you can get [This as a solution for the first equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xWOJ.png).
My problem is how to use this in the second one.
I can also provide the solution for the problem, however I don't know which steps to do how to get there.[Solution fo the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoJpF.png)

Thanks in advance

ln(x) + ln(y^2)=4 ;
(ln(x))^2 - 3ln(xy)=-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x>0$ and from here $y>0$.

Let $\ln{y}=t$.

Thus, $\ln{x}=4-2t$ and we obtain:
$$(4-2t)^2-3(2-2t)-3t=-5$$ or
$$4t^2-13t+9=0.$$
Can you end it now?

I got the following answer.
$$\left\{(e^2,e),\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}},e^{\frac{9}{4}}\right)\right\}$$

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much Sir! I can get that same solution now.

Comment: @user630424 You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x$ and $y$ to be positive. Then
$$\log()+\log(y^2)=4 \implies \log(x)+2\log(y)=4 \tag1$$
$$\log^2(x)-3\log(xy)=5 \implies \log^2(x)-3 \log(x)-3\log(y)=5 \tag 2$$

From $(1)$, express $\log(y)$ as a function of $\log(x)$. Replace in $(2)$ and you have a quadratic equation in $\log(x)$.

Comment: I see, when we then substitute ln(x) = t we get the same equation as Michael's. Thank you vey much for your help!

Comment: @user630424. You are welcome !